# Is Pip Bernadotte dead in Hellsing?

Tags: hellsing

In the anime, I saw Pip Bernadotte died. But when Seras was fighting the captain she summoned him as familiar, thus my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's just as dead at the one Alucard killed/consumed.
Physically dead, but he kinda lives on inside Seras' blood/soul.

If you'll remember, Alucard summons a lot of people he had killed and uses their powers in the last episode, it's the same here with pip. He'll be completely dead when Seras kills him from with her, like Alucard did with all his captured souls/familiar in the last bit.